# How to handle sessiontimeout, and redirect to login page when the page expires

Tags: struts

Iam using struts 1.3 in my application and iam new to it. My requirement is my
    application has to be redirected to the login page when the session expires. 
    Should i use an listeners for this purpose?
    Can any one explain me this concept in detail with relevant code

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to handle session timeout and redirecting to login page. Either you can redirect user action to login page after session gets expired or you can automatically redirect your page when session is expired. For more detail follow below link.

http://letslearnjavaj2ee.blogspot.in/2009/08/redirecting-to-jsp-page-after-user.html

There is one change is required in your case for second scenario "(2)Redirecting to a JSP Page automatically after the session gets expired. use

< meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%= session.getMaxInactiveInterval()%>;url=jsppage.jsp">

instead of using

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=session.getMaxInactiveInterval%>;url=/timeout.jsp" />
```

I hope you will get the answer.

Comment: This does not seem to work if used AJAX calls and the page is not reloaded. The server session remains valid in this case.